# SystemJs-bulder for angular, configuration

Tags: angular, systemjs

I need a little help, hint what I am doing wrong.
I have set up Angular and using SystemJs for loading modules. Due to slow loading (tons of modules) I am trying to set up systemjs-bulder.

I put bundle.js file in root dir and when I do node bundle.js I get:
node bundle.js

```
Unhandled rejection Error on translate for ts/app.js at file:///Users/mzoubek/Documents/Miha/www/GroupSweat/public/ts/app.js
    MultipleErrors: file:///Users/mzoubek/Documents/Miha/www/GroupSweat/public/ts/app.js:4:1: Unexpected token @
file:///Users/mzoubek/Documents/Miha/www/GroupSweat/public/ts/app.js:4:2: Semi-colon expected
```

My bundle.js file looks like this:

```
var SystemBuilder = require('systemjs-builder');
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var builder = new SystemBuilder();

builder.loadConfig('./system.config.js')
  .then(function(){
      var outputFile = argv.prod ? 'dist/bundle.min.js' : 'dist/bundle.js';
      return builder.buildStatic('app', outputFile, {
          minify: argv.prod,
          mangle: argv.prod,
          rollup: argv.prod
      });
  })
  .then(function(){
      console.log('bundle built successfully!');
  });
```

and system.config.js like this:

```
//configure system loader
System.config({
    map: {
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
        'app': 'ts'
    },
    packages: {
        'app': {
            main: 'app.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        '@angular/core': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        '@angular/compiler': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        '@angular/common': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        '@angular/platform-browser': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'rxjs': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
})
```

My folder structure is like this:

- nodule_modules/*
- index.html
- app.ts
- bundle.js
- system.config.js
- all files for angular to work...

And app.ts if it will help.

```
import { bootstrap } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'gs-test',
    template: `sss`
})


class groupSweatBoot {
    constructor() {

    }
}

bootstrap(groupSweatBoot);
```

thank you for all your help!